# Is there a way to reset the IsFirstRun in ClickOnce apps?

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

When the app first runs, it copies a short-cut into the startup folder. For testing on my local machine, I want to force the app to think it is its first run so I can re-test its installation process.  How do I do this?

Basically I need to know what sets this boolean to TRUE.  It must be something store in the ClickOnce cache or registry somehow...

```
ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.IsFirstRun
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have code something like this

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed && 
    ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.IsFirstRun)
{
    ...doing stuff
}
```

you could implement the following

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed && 
    ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.IsFirstRun)
{
     Settings.Default.IsFirstRun = false;
     Settings.Default.Save();
}

....

if (Settings.Default.IsFirstRun)
{
    // simply test here to see if its first run
    // you can just flip flag flag in the settings 
    // to acheive the same result.
}
```